# Changing PYTHONPATH on mac

Tags: python, macos, module, pythonpath

So I tried to change PYTHONPATH in mac terminal and this is how it went:

```
>>> PYTHONPATH = "${PYTHONPATH}:~/Desktop/Python/Modules"
>>> export PYTHONPATH
File "<stdin>", line 1
export PYTHONPATH
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be typing in `python` before you do this. Close your Terminal window, open a new one and type in those two commands. You might want to edit this into your `.profile` file as well.

Comment: @Blender What do you mean shouldn't be typing in python before doing this? How do I edit the .profile file? I feel pretty hopeless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type PYTHONPATH, you are typing in a command that is meant for your shell, not necessarily the python interpreter -- that is why you're getting a syntax error. What you want to do is set the pythonpath before you start the interpreter. When you set PYTHONPATH, you essentially give python's sys module another path in which to look for modules.

So like @Blender said, you'll want to start your terminal again, and from there, you'll want to type those two last commands again.